# Deciding to use at runtime a boost::static_vector or a std::vector

Tags: c++, boost

I have an application that I want to minimize dynamic allocation for efficiency.

I'm leaning forward using boost::static_vector in one of my classes for that reason. I'm not sure yet exactly how big my array will need to be to accommodate most situations but there are always exceptions...

Instead of discarding the input that would require more space than what my static_vector can store, I would like to fall back on std::vector to handle those exceptions.

A pattern that I commonly use in my classes design, is that I provide its input to the constructor to populate its container, then I provide a getter function that returns a const reference to the inner container.

The possibility that the class might use one or another container is causing a mental blind spot in me.

What would be the best way to offer access to the class elements?

I have come up with few ideas but none are truly satisfactory...

1. Make my class a container using the proxy/facade pattern
   I'm too lazy for doing that and this is not practical if I want to apply this static_vector/vector solution everywhere...
2. Place the burden on the class user
   ie.

```
void foo(HybridContainerObj &ojb) {
    if (obj.IsUsingStaticVector()) {
        const boost::static_vector<SomeElem> &vRef = obj.getStaticVec();
    }
    else {
        const std::vector<SomeElem> &vRef = obj.getVec();
    }
}
```

I doesn't feel right to me...

3. Modify boost::static_vector to do exactly what I have in mind

So far, this is my favorite solution...

4. Use some C++ magic that I am unaware of

Since both container classes do implement the same STL container concept, I wish that something along the lines would be possible:

`const auto &vecRef = obj.getVec();`

but AFAIK, this isn't possible... right?

So, I'm here to see what others think of that problem and if someone would have an elegant proposal to present the class used container elements to its users...

Greetings

Comment: Use C++20 and return a `std::span` (or use the one from the [GSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL)).

Comment: Deciding if it's appropriate to use dynamic memory or static memory is a user-space problem, not a library-writer problem. If you want to allocate 100 bytes in static memory, then any overflow of 50 more bytes ends up in dynamic memory. Or if you just start with 150 bytes of dynamic or static memory, you're still taking up 150 bytes of RAM.

Comment: Since you want to minimize dynamic memory, that implies you're memory constrained. In that case, what do you want to happen when the container reaches capacity? What should it return/throw if you try to add a 151st byte to your 150 byte container? Forget the implementation right now. What do you want the interface to be?

Comment: *"I want to minimize dynamic allocation for efficiency."* -- how is this more efficient? Let's say you choose a `static_vector` capacity of 100. That means each of these containers will statically allocate memory for 100 entries, even if you end up needing only 10 entries. A `vector`, on the other hand, potentially might dynamically allocate just enough memory for 10 entries. How is wasting the memory for 90 entries more efficient?

Comment: to clarify what I mean by efficiency, it is that I want to reduce the allocation overhead in terms of processing time. My program does process millions of those objects... I already have a memory pool for those objects but the fact that they possess a std::vector kinda defeat the purpose of the memory pool... I'm looking a way to address that issue. That is what motivated my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`boost::small_vector` may be the combination you are looking for. From https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost/container/small_vector.html:

> small_vector is a vector-like container optimized for the case when it
> contains few elements. It contains some preallocated elements
> in-place, which can avoid the use of dynamic storage allocation when
> the actual number of elements is below that preallocated threshold.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an "abstraction" over both `std::vector` and `boost::static_vector`, depending on what operations you want to do on the abstraction, you have different possibilities:

1. If you want const-access to the container, you can simply use a class that would wrap a raw array since both `std::vector` and `boost::static_vector` use a raw array internally. Fortunately for you, C++20 already has such class: [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) (if you don't have C++20, you can use the one from the [GSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL)). This is the preferred option since it is probably completely transparent in term of performance and the interface of `std::span` is close to the read-only operations of `std::vector` or `boost::static_vector`.
2. If you want more operations (e.g. being able to `push_back`, etc.), you'd need a proper abstraction similar to what `std::function` does for functor objects, which requires a lot more work:

```cpp
namespace details {
    template <class T>
    struct container_wrapper {
        // All the operations you need.
        virtual void push_back(T const& t) = 0;
    };

    template <class T>
    class vector_wrapper: public container_wrapper<T> {

        std::vector<T> *m_Vec;

    public:
        vector_wrapper(std::vector<T> &vec) : m_Vec{&vec} { }

        void push_back(T const& t) override {
            m_Vec->push_back(t);
        }
    };

    template <class T>
    struct static_vector_wrapper: public container_wrapper<T> {
        
        boost::static_vector<T> *m_Vec;
        
    public:
        vector_wrapper(boost::static_vector<T> &vec) : m_Vec{&vec} { }

        void push_back(T const& t) override {
            m_Vec->push_back(t);
        }
    };
}

template <class T>
class my_container {

    std::unique_ptr<details::container_wrapper> m_Wrapper;

public:
    my_container(std::vector<T> &vec) :
        m_Wrapper(std::make_unique<details::vector_wrapper<T>>(vec)) { }

    my_container(boost::static_vector<T> &vec) :
        m_Wrapper(std::make_unique<details::static_vector_wrapper<T>>(vec)) { }


};
```